# How to test with process.nextTick

Tags: node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js, sinon

I am using [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) to test some [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) code and want to use [`process.nextTick()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) to call a callback of a method.

### The Code

```
  @getNouns: (callback) ->
    @_wordnik.randomWords(
      includePartOfSpeech: 'noun',
      (e, result) ->
        throw new Error('Wordnik Failed') if e
        process.nextTick ->
          callback(result)
    )
```

### The Test

```
it 'should call a callback with the response', (done) ->
      sinon.stub(Word._wordnik, 'randomWords').yields(null, [
                              {id: 1234, word: "hello"},
                              {id: 2345, word: "foo"},
                              {id: 3456, word: "goodbye"}
                            ]
                          )
 
      spy = sinon.spy()

      Word.getNouns (result) -> spy(result); done(); null

      expect(spy).have.been.calledWith [
        {id: 1234, word: "hello"},
        {id: 2345, word: "foo"},
        {id: 3456, word: "goodbye"}
      ]
```

For some reason I am getting a `done()` was called twice error when I run mocha. If I run the callback outside of [`process.nextTick()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback).

Comment: Didn't quite get the last sentence -- what happens outside of `process.nextTick()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your test is calling `expect(spy).have.been.calledWith` before the spy was called via `spy(result)`.

I assume that when the expect fails, `done` is called for the first time (the test is done and failed). In the next tick, `done` is called again from your `getNouns` callback.

You don't need the spy to check the value passed to `getNouns` callback, you can do the assert immediately in the callback.

```
sinon.stub(Word._wordnik, 'randomWords').yields(null, [
                          {id: 1234, word: "hello"},
                          {id: 2345, word: "foo"},
                          {id: 3456, word: "goodbye"}
                        ]
                      )

Word.getNouns (result) ->
  expect(result).to.deep.equal [
    {id: 1234, word: "hello"},
    {id: 2345, word: "foo"},
    {id: 3456, word: "goodbye"}
  ]
  done()
```